# Chamaish Maiyos Ish

Tags: purim, megillat-esther

In the Shul I Daven in they say out loud besides the 4 Pesukim also Chamaish Maiyos Ish and Haman's 10 sons. What is the source of doing this?

Comment: I have heard that the logic is that _shomea k'one_ applies only to words spoken and not to the way they're said (e.g., in one breath) so that one cannot fulfill his obligation of saying the names in one breath by listening. I don't recall (if I ever heard) the source for this, and I don't know how whoever holds this deals with _shomea k'one_ for things that have to be said standing, sitting, while holding food, or in any other manner. (If the answer is that the listener is also standing, etc., then why can't he listen to the ten names while not taking a breath also?)

Comment: The source for this is the Rogatchover Gaon. And I guess the difference may be that bodily posture or whatever is sort of extrinsic to the words of the berachah, while here the "all in one breath" requirement is directly tied to the words being said.

Comment: How about putting it in as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rogatchover Gaon [writes](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22041&pgnum=114) (paragraph beginning ועיין תוספתא) that since there is an obligation to say the names of Haman's sons in one breath, then one can't fulfill this obligation by hearing someone else do this. Thus, each person in the congregation has to read these verses themselves.

Comment: Do we have any evidence that this was done before 150 years ago?